# What are and how can I unserstand/process geo levels id from this dataset?

Tags: dataset, predictive-modeling

I am using the dataset from this driven data competition: https://www.drivendata.org/competitions/57/nepal-earthquake/data/

There are three features (geo_level_id_1, geo_level_id_2, geo_level_id_3) that indicates the physical land where the observation is, but I don´t know how can I used it for building a predictive model. Even if this kind of data is universal, I mean, if it is a common way to represent places (such as latitude and longitude).

This data and the others features are described here: https://www.drivendata.org/competitions/57/nepal-earthquake/page/136/#features_list

Do you recommend me some reading or study to understand better this issue?

Thanks a lot!